# Unit testing a config file read returning a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to do a unit test for the below function that reads a set of index create statements from a config file placed in a s3 location using the configparser.

```
def read_config(configparser, bucket, file, section, key):
   s3client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-east-1')
   obj = s3client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=file)
   config = configparser.ConfigParser()
   config.read_string(obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'))
   return config[section][key].split('\n')
```

I have come up with the below code for the unit test.

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock

@mock.patch('boto3.client')
class TestFunctions(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('configparser.ConfigParser')
    def test_read_config(self, mock_config_parser, mock_boto3_client):
        mock_s3_client = mock.Mock()
        mock_boto3_client.return_value = mock_s3_client
        mock_body = mock.Mock()
        mock_body.read.return_value = b"""
        [idx_list]
        idx1 = create index emp1 on employee (empid asc)
        """
        mock_s3_client.get_object.return_value = {'Body': mock_body}
        mock_config = mock_config_parser.return_value
        mock_config.read_string.return_value = None
        mock_config.get.return_value = 'create index emp1 on employee (empid asc)'
        result = read_config(mock_config, 'bucket', 'file.ini', 'idx_list', 'idx1')
        # Assertions
        self.assertEqual(result, ['create index emp1 on employee (empid asc)'])
        mock_s3_client.get_object.assert_called_with(Bucket='bucket', Key='file.ini')
        mock_config.get.assert_called_with('idx_list', 'idx1')
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

But the value of the result variable is being returned as `MagicMock name='ConfigParser().ConfigParser().get()' id='2694479565872'` instead of the original intended value due to which I am getting an assertion error.

Could anyone please help me in understanding the issue.

Comment: It's not clear why you are mocking `ConfigParser` in the first place. Assume `ConfigParser` works as documented; all you care about with regard to `read_config` is that `read_config('bucket', 'file.ini', 'idx_list', 'idx')` returns a certain string, after `boto3.client` is patched to provide an in-memory file to parse.

Comment: @chepner, thank you for looking into the issue! I chose to mock ConfigParser because the original function is using ConfigParser to parse the ini file and read the particular section and key from it. Are you suggesting that I use the ConfigParser library as it is in the test function rather than mocking it up?

Comment: I would also suggest moving all the S3 stuff out of `read_config` entirely; let it focus on reading from some file-like object and parsing what gets read. `def read_config(f, section, key): config = ...; config.read_string(f.read().decode('utf-8')); return ...`. Now instead of mocking *anything*, you just pass an `io.BytesIO` value as the first argument. Granted, there may still be some code that *does* have to interface with S3 that still needs testing, but now that code isn't also concerned with *doing* anything with the contents of any particular object.

Comment: Further, I'd define `def read_config_from_s3(s3client, bucket, file, section, key): obj = s3client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, File=file); ...` Now you don't need to *patch* anything, but simply define a `Mock` object to pass as the first argument to `read_config_from_s3`.